# postgresql find preceding and following timestamp to arbitrary timestamp

Tags: postgresql

Given an arbitrary timestamp such as `2014-06-01 12:04:55-04` I can find in sometable the timestamps just before and just after. I then calculate the elapsed number of seconds between those two with the following query:

```
SELECT EXTRACT (EPOCH FROM (
  (SELECT time AS t0 
    FROM sometable 
    WHERE time < '2014-06-01 12:04:55-04' 
    ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1) -
  (SELECT time AS t1
    FROM sometable
    WHERE time > '2014-06-01 12:04:55-04' 
    ORDER BY time ASC LIMIT 1)
)) as elapsedNegative;
```

`
It works, but I was was wondering if there was another more elegant or astute way to achieve the same result? I am using 9.3. Here is a toy database.

```
CREATE TABLE sometable (
id serial,
time timestamp
);

INSERT INTO sometable (id, time) VALUES (1, '2014-06-01 11:59:37-04');
INSERT INTO sometable (id, time) VALUES (1, '2014-06-01 12:02:22-04');
INSERT INTO sometable (id, time) VALUES (1, '2014-06-01 12:04:49-04');
INSERT INTO sometable (id, time) VALUES (1, '2014-06-01 12:07:35-04');
INSERT INTO sometable (id, time) VALUES (1, '2014-06-01 12:09:53-04');
```

Thanks for any tips...

**update** Thanks to both @Joe Love and @Clément Prévost for interesting alternatives. Learned a lot on the way!

Comment: `lag()` & `lead()` window functions calculates just what you need http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html -- also, timestamp difference can be easily calculated with its operators (no need for multiple `extract()` calls) http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html

Comment: @pozs Thanks, I am aware of these functions. However since my arbitrary timestamp is not part of the table, it is not obvious to me how to get the _first below_ or _first above_...

Comment: Your query looks VERY effective, given that the sometable.time column is indexed, your execution plan should look 2 index scans (index only scans if you have pg 9.2 and above). Do you have any performance issues ?

Comment: @Clément Prévost No, no performance issues. Since I am very green with SQL, I assumed my code might not be very optimal. Glad to find out it was not bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original query can't be more effective given that the sometable.time column is indexed, your execution plan should show only 2 index scans, which is very efficient (index only scans if you have pg 9.2 and above).

Here is a more readable way to write it

```
WITH previous_timestamp AS (
    SELECT time AS time 
    FROM sometable 
    WHERE time < '2014-06-01 12:04:55-04' 
    ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1
), 
next_timestamp AS (
    SELECT time AS time
    FROM sometable
    WHERE time > '2014-06-01 12:04:55-04' 
    ORDER BY time ASC LIMIT 1
)
SELECT EXTRACT (EPOCH FROM (
  (SELECT * FROM next_timestamp) 
  - (SELECT * FROM previous_timestamp)
))as elapsedNegative;
```

Using CTE allow you to give meaning to a subquery by naming it. Explicit naming is a well known and recognised coding best practice (use explicit names, don't abbreviate and don't use over generic names like "data" or "value").

Be warned that CTE are optimisation "fences" and sometimes get in the way of planner optimisation

Here is [the SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/788f5/12).

*Edit: Moved the extract from the CTE to the final query so that PostgreSQL can use a index only scan.*

Comment: More readable indeed. Benchmarking came out at 52.761 ms which I will assume may be the fencing effect your alluded to. Referring to my comment to @Joe Love, the time column is not indexed...

Comment: Oh, if the column is not indexed that is another story. Then the planner must choose a sequential scan because he don't have any idea what's in the table. Then the data is rapidly found in the data pages and the LIMIT clause end the query very fast. You should get inconsistent timings depending on the data position in the physical table. Could you try with other values for the date ?

Comment: I will try at various position, however in the meantime I just read that setting time as a PRIMARY KEY is actually the same as setting it an INDEX...

Comment: This is true but these are not the same kind of operation. When you create a primary key in PostgreSQL, the databases automatically creates an index on this column. Primary keys should be used when the meaning of "identifier" for the whole row is respected. If not, use UNIQUE constraints and indexes.

Comment: At various positions the results came at 0.111, 0.181, 0.219, 0.184 ms. BTW I do have a unique constraint on the time column as well since the data sources had massive record overlap/duplication.

Comment: Ok so if you have a unique constraint, your time column is indexed (postgresql does that automatically for you too). I need to work on the explain plan to determine how to overcome the optimisation fencing effect :D

Comment: Is this solution better performing ?

Comment: Moving the CTE to the final query brings it down to sub-ms 0.522 ms. Kudos!

Answer (score 1):

This solution will likely perform better if the timestamp column does not have an index. When 9.4 comes out we can do it a little shorter by using aggregate filters.

This should be a bit bit faster as it's running 1 full table scan instead of 2, however it may perform worse, if your timestamp column is indexed and you have a large dataset.

Here's the example without the epoch conversion to make it more easy to read.

```
select 
min(
case when start_timestamp > current_timestamp
then
start_timestamp
else 'infinity'::timestamp
end 
),
max(
case when t1.start_timestamp < current_timestamp
then
start_timestamp
else '-infinity'::timestamp
end 
)
 from my_table as t1
```

And here's the example including the math and epoch extraction:

```
select
extract (EPOCH FROM (
min(
case when start_timestamp > current_timestamp
then
start_timestamp
else 'infinity'::timestamp
end 
)-
max(
case when start_timestamp < current_timestamp
then
start_timestamp
else '-infinity'::timestamp
end 
)))
 from snap.offering_event
```

Please let me know if you need further details-- I'd recommend trying my code vs yours and seeing how it performs.

Comment: It is hard to say that yours is faster, it can be for small tables, as it is one table scan, but for big tables the OP's version might have better performance as it means two fast index lookups. Also, I don't understand why you say your version is slow if there is an index, it cannot use an index on this column anyway.

Comment: Without an index, it certainly appears faster with the data I've generated, with a btree index, it's probably faster-- I'd forgotten the btree index can be used to shortcut the order by and order by desc.

Comment: @Joe Love. Thanks, using CASE makes it very readable. For the record (only 30 000 rows) my original query ran in 0.772 ms and yours in 37.916 ms.

Comment: I'm assuming that your timestamp field is indexed?

Comment: That's the part that I find strange: it is not indexed. However all records were entered in chronological order using the ogr2ogr (a geospatial tool). Could that bring similar benefits??

Comment: It's possible that my query uses quite a bit more CPU (usually queries are IO bound and not heavy CPU users).. since I've got 2 case statements and a max and a min, then perhaps that's it.. small things like the -infinity timestamp could play a roll, but it's hard to say without doing a lot more benchmark tests

Comment: Also, did you run the timing multiple times on each query? Times this short are likely to vary widely.